# Fake file handle creation

Tags: php, file, file-io

This is probably impossible but i thought i would ask around and see if i missed something. What im looking for is a way of using functions that require file pointer handle without the need to write an actual file.

I know i could use a temporary file, do my operations then read the file back into the output buffer and delete the file. However this means latency from writing to disk then reading from the disk. It would be far better for speed and resources in my case if i could just do something like

```
$tmp = createFakeFile();
fputscsv($tmp, array(/*** an array of csv fields ***/));
echo $tmp;
```

I doubt this exists but if you've ever heard of a way of doing something like this i'd love to hear about it

Thanks

Comment: I'm sure there's a way to achieve the same thing without using a file. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I've come across this numerous times before where a fake file would be beneficial. The case thats now prompted me to post is im creating a csv of data, but i just want to shove the data into the output stream and not store it. I could create a temp file or write my own function that does it without the file requirement, but i already know how to get around the issue, its more of a case of wondering whether its possible to actually use fake file pointers rather than using work arounds or 3rd party functions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use php://memory and php://temp wrapper files for this.

Cite:

> php://memory and php://temp are read-write streams that allow
>   temporary data to be stored in a file-like wrapper. The only
>   difference between the two is that php://memory will always store its
>   data in memory, whereas php://temp will use a temporary file once the
>   amount of data stored hits a predefined limit (the default is 2 MB).
>   The location of this temporary file is determined in the same way as
>   the sys_get_temp_dir() function.
>
> The memory limit of php://temp can be controlled by appending
>   /maxmemory:NN, where NN is the maximum amount of data to keep in
>   memory before using a temporary file, in bytes.

http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Comment: Thanks, i'll have a look around. I infact just wrote a few lines of code after a brainwave about php://stdout ... Why is it i always think of solutions after i make a post and not before :)

Answer (score 2):

There is indeed a way to do it: [`stream_wrapper_register()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-wrapper-register.php).

[This](http://www.php.net/manual/en/stream.streamwrapper.example-1.php) example class should do what you want, it creates a file handle that is actually just held in memory.

Having said that, so does [`php://memory`](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) and to some degree, [`php://temp`](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php).